# angular2 style body from a component with css

Tags: angular

How can I style the body tag from the stylesheet of a component using ONLY css (no host-binding solution, no view encapsulation solution, no ...)

I tried this but it doesn't work (sass)

```
* >>> body
  overflow: hidden
```

I tried this too

```
body /deep/
  overflow: hidden
```

this is my index.html

```
<body>

<app-root></app-root>

</body>
```

Comment: Not sure if this is hostbinding why not just use                                     
           body{ overflow:hidden}

Comment: I need to do this inside a component and remove when destroyed. The problem is you can't style elements outside of your compoenent

Comment: Check out this example, it should help: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-theme-service

Answer (score 8):

Due to encapsulation you can't refer to parent. What you could do is inject the element ref, and then use js to set it:

```
constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {
   elRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
```

and then in your destroy hook:

```
this.elRef.nativeElement.ownerDocument.body.style.overflow = null
```

Comment: Or you can do `document.body.style...` ?

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this issue with:

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'realtime-tooltip',
    template: '',
    styles: [`
        .nvtooltip.xy-tooltip tr:nth-child(2),
        .nvtooltip.xy-tooltip tr:nth-child(4) {
            display: none;
    }
    `],
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})
export class RealtimeTooltip {}

@Component({
    selector: 'realtime-audience-graph',
    template: require('./realtime-audience-graph.component.html'),
    styles: [require('./realtime-audience-graph.component.scss')]
})

export class RealtimeAudienceGraph {}
```

The style was outside the component and I've included this component in the component html.

```
<realtime-tooltip></realtime-tooltip>
```

ViewEncapsulation set to none will allow for styling of any element outside the component.
The main component will still have the default encapsulation.

Answer (score -1):

You can do that simply from index.html

```
<body style="overflow: hidden;">

<app-root></app-root>

</body>
```

Comment: not relevant solution as it was asked to do it inside a component (let say inside a modal component)

Comment: the problem is styling a tag/element from inside the component. this maybe dynamic based on component.